# Frequency distribution of words

Tags: java, algorithm

I have read in two txt files with words.

Now I was wondering how to calculate the frequency distribution of these two Strings. My idea is to put them into an array and split them by `;`. However, how to calculated the frequency distribution?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Well, if you simply want frequency of each word, put the words in a *collection* and call `Collections.frequency()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code is something like this:

```
    String str1 = "java;python;javascript;programming;Hello;World;Hello";
    String str2 = "java;python;javascript;programming;Hello;World;Hello";

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str1.split(";")));
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str2.split(";")));

    for (String word : list) 
        System.out.println(word + " --> " + Collections.frequency(list,word));
```

Comment: This will count and print the same words multiple times (e.g. `"Hello"`).